# How to properly translate "Passing Yachtsmen?"

Tags: participle, глаголы-движения

I came across the phrase, "Passing yachtsmen raised the alarm after spotting him..." Could I say the following using the verb `плавать` with the prefix `про` to indicate passing in order to bypass using the participle.

```
Яхтсмены, которые проплавали, поднимали тревогу...
```

How would I say this properly using the a participle for "Passing yachtsmen?" I basically don't understand how to form a participle with a prefixed verb of motion or even how to form a regular participle. I can just recognize them in text.

Comment: _...кото́рые проплы̲ва́ли_, not _пропла́вали_. Participle should be _Проплыва́вшие яхтсме́ны_ (past tense) or _Проплыва́ющие яхтсме́ны_ (present), both would be grammatically correct here. And, though I do not know the context of course, but most probably you want to say _подня́ли трево́гу_ / _по́дняли трево́гу_ (perfective) rather than _поднима́ли_ (imperfective).

Comment: "Проплывавшие мимо яхтсмены подняли тревогу"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*...кото́рые пропл**ы**ва́ли* (from unidirectional motion verb *плы́ть*), not *пропла́вали* (from multidirectional / cyclical *пла́вать*), cf. unidirectional *езжа́ть* → *проезжа́ющие*. As for prefix, I doubt that it can ever affect the way how a participle is formed. So it may be *Проплыва́вшие яхтсме́ны* (past participle) or *Проплыва́ющие яхтсме́ны* (present participle), both would be grammatically correct here.

And, though I do not know the context of course, most probably you want to say *подня́ли трево́гу* / *по́дняли трево́гу* (perfective) rather than *поднима́ли* (imperfective).

Answer (score 2):

`Passing yachtsmen` it's definitely `проплывающие яхтсмены`

adverbial participle of static actions usually don't have a prefix `про`, compare:

> Читащий, решающий, говорящий

but some statically active (dynamic action in static position) can be with `про`

> проигрывающий (сидит на месте, но проигывает) , проворачивающий (сидит на месте, но проворачивает),

adverbial participles of motion usually have, compare:

> проходящий, проплывающий, пробегающий, пролетающий, проползающий

Comment: _Проплыва́вшие_ is no worse.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov you didn't make an answer, what do you mean by saying `is no worse`, you downvote me just because your comment `is no worse` than my answer? Well, it's just ridiculous then. I put right answer, what do you have?

Comment: By “Проплыва́вшие is no worse” I meant that it is no worse than _Проплыва́ющие_ here, while your insist (“definitely”) on the latter. As for downvote, the *only* reason for downvoting may be that the answer is wrong or unrelated. I considered that partially wrong in the first sentence and mostly unrelated to question (Nikita did not asked about usage of _про-_) in the rest. That‘s all. But if you are susceptible to downvotes :-), I can withdraw it (done).

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Forget about votes, I'm here to help others with Russian learining, but Nikita asked `How would I say this properly using the a participle for "Passing yachtsmen?" I basically don't understand how to form a participle with a prefixed verb of motion or even how to form a regular participle.` So I first translated for him `passing yachtsmen` and then tried explaining for `form a participle with a prefixed`. I kept in mind that you previously tried to answer in the comment and that you covered the whole sentence with translation and probably you were going to commit an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous answers, considering nautical/sailor own professional language, probably `проходившие яхтсмены` could be better sounding than `проплывавшие`. My father was in Soviet Navy and he *still* hates saying or hearing something like *"корабль плывёт"*, reasoning like *"плавают люди, а корабли ходят"*, hence he argues *"моряки ходят на кораблях"*, and *"моряк плывёт"* in his opinion explicitly means *"a sailor swims"*, not *"a seaman sails"*.